# Using SQL Server to get centroid of three circles intersecting

Tags: sql-server, spatial, intersect

I've been a long time GIS person but have recently been working in spatial side of SQL Server. I'm using SQL Server 2016 Express.

I'd like to get centroid of the polygon that is the intersection of these three circles. The Intersection should be a very small polygon (30 feet across or so).  However, my intersection creates a huge polygon.

Obviously I am doing something wrong.  Is that not how intersection works?

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable
(   
    [Latitude] dec(15,10),
    [Longitude] dec(15,10),
    Dist dec(15,10), 
    ID varchar(4),
    myGeog geography,
    MyBuff geography
)

INSERT INTO #myTable 
VALUES (36.808838,  -119.792923, 347.2867998,'zX0', NULL,NULL),
       (36.145789,  -120.359316, 388.3265656,'zX1', NULL,NULL),
       (31.333473,  -110.867344, 1351.14404,'zX2', NULL,NULL)

UPDATE mt
SET myGeog = geography::Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326)
FROM #myTable mt

UPDATE mt
SET MyBuff = myGeog.STBuffer(Dist*1000)
FROM #myTable mt

DECLARE @myB1 geography  
DECLARE @myB2 geography  
DECLARE @myB3 geography  

SET @myB1 = (SELECT MyBuff FROM #myTable WHERE ID = 'zX0')
SET @myB2 = (SELECT MyBuff FROM #myTable WHERE ID = 'zX1')
SET @myB3 = (SELECT MyBuff FROM #myTable WHERE ID = 'zX2')

SELECT  @myB1.STIntersection(@myB2.STIntersection(@myB3))
SELECT @myB1.STIntersection(@myB2.STIntersection(@myB3)).ToString()    

DROP TABLE #myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Your result is correct. If you just run:

```
SELECT MyBuff FROM #myTable;
```

And look at the 3 polygons it draws together and the result of your intersection, you will see that it is truly the intersection.  I think it may just be that it zooms in and blows up the scale of your intersection results.

[image: picture of the results]